# How to Redirect an Old Domain to a New Domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have created a .htaccess file, containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

and then uploaded this file to oldsite's server through FileZilla, but when I load oldsite.com its not redirecting to newsite.com

Comment: Does your old server have mod_rewrite enabled? Do they allow you to use custom rewrite rules?

Comment: actually i dont know whether my old server have mode_rewrite enabled or not, i need to check it first.  thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Create a CNAME record in a zone **oldsite.com** like that:
`oldsite.com. IN CNAME newsite.com.`